# Remove an <li> tag completely from View

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-lists

I have an array object from a son API and I want to display only the first 3 items and hide the rest of the items.

Unfortunately when I try to hide the rest of the items from the view it still shows that a list was there but hidden. I want to hide that completely without destroying the values in that list.

My code below

```
$characters = json_decode($data);
foreach ($characters as $character) {

    <?php echo "<li style='display:none'>".$character->name . '<br>'."</li>"; ?>

}
```

Comment: do you want to use visible: false?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_slice` method to create another array with reduced number of items (for your example, that'd be 3).

**Solution for your Example:**

```
<?php echo "<li>". array_slice($character, 0, 3)->name . '<br>'."</li>"; ?>
```

**More info about array_slice method:**

> array_slice() returns the sequence of elements from the array array as
>   specified by the offset and length parameters.

```
array_slice(array,start,length,preserve)
```

**array:** The input array.

**offset:** `number`

- The offset parameter denotes the position in the array, not the key. If offset is non-negative, the sequence will start at that offset in the array. If offset is negative, the sequence will start that far from the end of the array.

**length:** `number`

- If length is given and is positive, then the sequence will have up to that many elements in it.
- If the array is shorter than the length, then only the available array elements will be present.
- If length is given and is negative then the sequence will stop that many elements from the end of the array.
- If it is omitted, then the sequence will have everything from offset up until the end of the array.

**preserve_keys:** `boolean`

- array_slice() will reorder and reset the integer array indices by default. This behavior can be changed by setting preserve_keys to TRUE. String keys are always preserved, regardless of this parameter.

Comment: I have this error Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in

Comment: Seems your $character is an object. You need to **convert $character into an array** before passing to *array_slice()* method. Try typecasting by appending `(array)` before `$character`

Comment: Try this -> 
`array_slice((array)$character, 0, 3)->name`